# Create contact with ContactGroups & BrandingTheme data?

Tags: xero-api

Is it possible to include ContactGroups & BrandingTheme data during contract creation via API? As those two doesn't seems to be included in the API documentation

Thanks

Create contact ContactGroups & BrandingTheme data via API

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to populate the branding theme or contact group from the contacts endpoint.

You can use the contactgroups endpoint to add the contact to a group.

Adding a default branding theme for a contact would need to be done by a user in Xero